# Few tips how to speed up saving product in magento

Tags: performance, api, magento

currently I'm trying to work out how to speed up saving of product in magento. We're importing products via Magento API and each product takes ages to update. There is tons of observers which are triggered on catalog_product_save_* event.

Have you any tips what observers are not important and I can disable them or what I can disable with low impack.

Thansk for any advices.
Jaro

Answer (score 3):

Just set Index mode to "Manual" for all indexes.
So magento won't run reindex after every product save.
Don't forget to set them back to normal and run full reindex after product import is finished.

Comment: This cannot help to me, because API sends product update randomly and I cannot disable/enable indexing manualy, it's not feasible for me. Thanks for reply.

Answer (score 3):

Process that takes most time after product save is indexer.
You can set index mode to `manual` programatically like this:

```
$indexers = Mage::getSingleton('index/indexer')->getProcessesCollection(); 
foreach ($indexers as $indexer) {
   $indexer->setMode(Mage_Index_Model_Process::MODE_MANUAL)->save();
}
```

And after import set it to `auto`:

```
$indexers = Mage::getSingleton('index/indexer')->getProcessesCollection(); 
foreach ($indexers as $indexer) {
   $indexer->setMode(Mage_Index_Model_Process::MODE_REAL_TIME)->save();

 }
```

Also depending on what you're importing you may want to reindex your data.

List of possible indexes:

> 1. Product Attributes
> 2. Product Prices
> 3. Catalog URL Rewrites
> 4. Product Flat Data
> 5. Category Flat Data
> 6. Category Products
> 7. Catalog Search index
> 8. Tag Aggregation Data
> 9. Stock Status

To perform reindex:

```
$process = Mage::getModel('index/process')->load($id);
$process->reindexAll();
```

Where `$id` is a list index from above list.

Comment: This really helps, usualy the greediest process is search index. I know about this. My question is more pointed to catalog_product_save_after and catalog_product_save_before observers. Here can be another performance issues. Do you know about any of them which can help if I disable them and process them layer?